# How to apply a basic transition to a text when hovering over an image in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a container `<div>` with 3 images inside it as
[image: before :hover]

And I have 3 `<div>`'s below them containing some text that gets displayed when a respective image gets hovered over like this:

[image]

This is my code, I'm using React:

```
        <div className = "Page">
        <div className = "About">
            <h1 className = "Headerr-1">We at flower shop</h1>
            <h1 className = "Headerr-2">dedicate ourselves to providing you the best flowers for all occations</h1>

            <p className = "paragraph-1"> we use some of the best tools to fertilize our flowers so it can meet your every need</p>
            <p className = "paragraph-2" >here is some testimoney from our clients</p>


            <div className = " testimony-container">

                <img src = {Man} width = "400" height = "400" className = "man-img" />
                <img src = {Woman} width = "400" height = "400" className = "woman-img" />
                <img src = {Miles} width = "400" height = "400" className = "miles-img" />

                <div className = "man-text-container">
                    <p className = "man-p"> ''I was in dire need of a quick way to get my flowers
                        on time for my wedding day, I would like to thank Flower
                        Shop for their efforts on showing up in time.''</p>
                    <p className = "man-title">
                        -Melvin Jones
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div className = "woman-text-container">
                    <p className = "woman-p"> ''I needed some fresh picked flowers as a gift for my
                    grandmother's birthday, and a friend referenced flowershop to me. Suffice to say
                        I don't have any regrets!''
                    </p>
                    <p className = "woman-title">
                    -Vanessa Richardson 
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div className = "miles-text-container">
                    <p className = "miles-p"> ''An old friend of mine was sick and I was looking to
                    purchase some flowers as a gift and send it to the hospital where he was resting.
                    I thank Flower Shop for their beautifully picked flowers.''
                    </p>
                    <p className = "miles-title">
                    -Miles Edgeworth
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

What I'm trying to do is to add a basic transition that reveals the text in a slow fashion. I tried using `opacity` but the text just started running towards the screen in a weird fashion when I want the text to fade in and out on the hover action.

What is the best approach towards this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using opacity worked fine for me:

```
.man-text-container, 
.miles-text-container, 
.woman-text-container {
    opacity:0;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;  
    -moz-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.man-img:hover~.man-text-container, 
.woman-img:hover~.woman-text-container, 
.miles-img:hover~.miles-text-container {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

What did your CSS look like?

Comment: https://codepen.io/mu-al-dulaimi/pen/rNjRQqw   for some reason I couldn't directly copy paste the code here so I saved it on codepen. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The issue is that you are setting things like `font-size: 2.2rem;` and `text-align: center;` in the :hover selectors, instead of applying those to the normal selector first. That's why the text is moving around when you hover on the image, because it is resizing and moving it along with making it visible. You can take everything out of the `.man-img:hover ~ .man-text-container` selector except for what you want to change, which is `opacity: 1;'. Move everything else to the containers. https://codepen.io/robertjhull/pen/ZELPwyN